# How to get rid of the property grid warnings?

Tags: compiler-errors, g++, wxwidgets, compiler-warnings

I always get this warnings:
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jS5t3r/ccb8a6e3db18d5133d37986b8979baef/raw/f4750f5ac3211b0560d27b035d31542877669e07/warnings

I am using

- ArchLinux
- gcc (GCC) 6.2.1 20160830
- wxwidget 3.0

I use those flags for compilng

```
WXWIDGETSFLAGS=`wx-config --gl-libs --cxxflags --libs std stc propgrid richtext`
```

Warnings:

```
g++ `wx-config --gl-libs --cxxflags --libs std stc propgrid richtext`  -std=c++11 -Wall -Iinclude  source/wxwidget/GUIMemLayMgr.h source/wxwidget/gui.h source/wxwidget/GUIMemLayMgr.cpp source/wxwidget/gui.cpp  source/wxwidget/main.cpp -o output/wxwidget
In file included from /usr/include/wx-3.0/wx/propgrid/propgrid.h:26:0,
             from source/wxwidget/gui.h:31,
             from source/wxwidget/GUIMemLayMgr.h:9:
/usr/include/wx-3.0/wx/propgrid/property.h: In member function 'void  wxPGChoices::Set(const wxArrayString&, const wxArrayInt&)':
/usr/include/wx-3.0/wx/propgrid/property.h:1049:22: warning: the compiler can assume that the address of 'values' will always evaluate to 'true' [-Waddress]
     if ( &values )
                  ^
/usr/include/wx-3.0/wx/propgrid/property.h:1049:22: warning: the compiler can assume that the address of 'values' will always evaluate to 'true' [-Waddress]
In file included from /usr/include/wx-3.0/wx/propgrid/propgrid.h:26:0,
             from source/wxwidget/gui.h:31:
/usr/include/wx-3.0/wx/propgrid/property.h: In member function 'void wxPGChoices::Set(const wxArrayString&, const wxArrayInt&)':
/usr/include/wx-3.0/wx/propgrid/property.h:1049:22: warning: the compiler can assume that the address of 'values' will always evaluate to 'true' [-Waddress]
     if ( &values )
                  ^
/usr/include/wx-3.0/wx/propgrid/property.h:1049:22: warning: the compiler can assume that the address of 'values' will always evaluate to 'true' [-Waddress]
In file included from /usr/include/wx-3.0/wx/propgrid/propgrid.h:26:0,
             from source/wxwidget/gui.h:31,
             from source/wxwidget/GUIMemLayMgr.h:9,
             from source/wxwidget/GUIMemLayMgr.cpp:1:
/usr/include/wx-3.0/wx/propgrid/property.h: In member function 'void wxPGChoices::Set(const wxArrayString&, const wxArrayInt&)':
/usr/include/wx-3.0/wx/propgrid/property.h:1049:22: warning: the compiler  can assume that the address of 'values' will always evaluate to 'true' [-Waddress]
     if ( &values )
                  ^
/usr/include/wx-3.0/wx/propgrid/property.h:1049:22: warning: the compiler can assume that the address of 'values' will always evaluate to 'true' [-Waddress]
In file included from /usr/include/wx-3.0/wx/propgrid/propgrid.h:26:0,
             from source/wxwidget/gui.h:31,
             from source/wxwidget/gui.cpp:8:
/usr/include/wx-3.0/wx/propgrid/property.h: In member function 'void   wxPGChoices::Set(const wxArrayString&, const wxArrayInt&)':
/usr/include/wx-3.0/wx/propgrid/property.h:1049:22: warning: the  compiler can assume that the address of 'values' will always evaluate to 'true' [-Waddress]
     if ( &values )
                  ^
/usr/include/wx-3.0/wx/propgrid/property.h:1049:22: warning: the compiler can assume that the address of 'values' will always evaluate to 'true' [-Waddress]
In file included from /usr/include/wx-3.0/wx/propgrid/propgrid.h:26:0,
             from source/wxwidget/gui.h:31,
             from source/wxwidget/main.cpp:22:
/usr/include/wx-3.0/wx/propgrid/property.h: In member function 'void wxPGChoices::Set(const wxArrayString&, const wxArrayInt&)':
/usr/include/wx-3.0/wx/propgrid/property.h:1049:22: warning: the compiler can assume that the address of 'values' will always evaluate to 'true' [-Waddress]
     if ( &values )
                  ^
/usr/include/wx-3.0/wx/propgrid/property.h:1049:22: warning: the compiler can assume that the address of 'values' will always evaluate to 'true' [-Waddress]
```

Comment: it is very hard to say something without seeing the code. However its just a warning and if the progrm runs OK, you can disregard.

Comment: You should really include the error messages in your question instead of relying on an external link.

Comment: @Igor I would not just ignore warnings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That was fixed in [Optimize wxPGChoices::Set method](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/commit/d04c8569ca64446170a8e158a73beb18d1d813f6) commit, which was after `3.0.2`. To use it you need to get latest `3.0` branch from git or `3.1.0` version - basically anything after that commit.

Comment: wx-config --version                                                                                                                                                                                                            
3.0.2 This version I am using.

Comment: A short answer would be "use `3.1.0`".

Answer (score 0):

I changed the include from

```
#include <wx/propgrid/propgrid.h>
```

to

```
#include <wx-3.0/wx/propgrid/propgrid.h>
```

Now it is working fine.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a correct approach. Changing the headers, but not using the source files corresponding to the new headers is not ok.

Comment: In addition to what the previous comment says, this can't really change anything at all...

Comment: @catalin I think, if I use <wx/propgrid/propgrid.h> I use a wxwidget version older than 3.0.2. With this hack hack I am using 3.0.2. How I should solve it?